# A series of fortunate transpositions

Tags: wordplay, no-computers, graph-theory, sliding-blocks, word-ladder

Using only a sequence of transpositions, see if you can take this:

[image: start_state]

to this:

[image: finish_state]

while maintaining English words on each of the three horizontals.

At each step, you may transpose any two neighboring letters, either up-down or left-right.

At each step, you must have three horizontal English words.

All the words along the way should be common and familiar (certainly no less familiar than LUSHER).  No need to reach for the dictionary.

---

If you want a similar puzzle but with more horizontal action, please see the exciting sequel [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93123/another-series-of-fortunate-and-sideways-transpositions).

Comment: Q:  Can you use "lusher" in a sentence?

Comment: A:  "And we came upon yet another meadow, each meadow greener and lusher than the last..."

Comment: another high-quality transposition puzzle! *applauds in happiness*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using all vertical transpositions. All changes annotated and words defined.

- > MATTED [starting word]
  >  BASHES [starting word]
  >  LUSHER [starting word]
- > MATTED [no change]
  >  BASHE**R** (one who hits)
  >  LUSHE**S** (drunk people)
- > **B**ATTED (hit, as a baseball)
  >  **M**ASHER (kitchen tool, for crushing)
  >  LUSHES [no change]
- > BAT**H**ED (cleaned, as in a shower)
  >  MAS**T**ER (boss)
  >  LUSHES [no change]
- > BATHED [no change]
  >  M**U**STER (assemble, in the military)
  >  L**A**SHES (ties to)
- > BA**S**HED (hit, in the past)
  >  MU**T**TER (grumble)
  >  LASHES [no change]
- > BASHED [no change]
  >  M**A**TTER (be relevant)
  >  L**U**SHES [seen before]
- > BASHED [no change]
  >  **L**ATTER (last in a series)
  >  **M**USHES (runs a team of sled dogs; I almost didn't submit because this isn't a super-common word, but then I saw there was an existing answer and it used MUSHES and the author didn't complain about it)
- > **L**ASHED (tied to)
  >  **B**ATTER (baseball player on offense)
  >  MUSHES [no change]
- > LASHED [no change]
  >  B**U**TTER (dairy product)
  >  M**A**SHES (crushes, as potatoes)
- > LASHE**R** (one who ties)
  >  BUTTE**D** (cut in line)
  >  MASHES [no change]
- > L**U**SHER [seen before]
  >  B**A**TTED [seen before]
  >  MASHES [no change]
- > LUSHER [no change]
  >  **M**ATTED [seen before]
  >  **B**ASHES [seen before]
- > LUSHER [no change]
  >  MATTE**S** (not glossy or shiny; plural)
  >  BASHE**D** [seen before]
- > **M**USHER (one who runs sled dogs)
  >  **L**ATTES (coffees)
  >  BASHED [no change]
- > MUSHER [no change]
  >  LAT**H**ES (rotating tools)
  >  BAS**T**ED (injected liquid into, as with food)
- > MUSHE**S** [seen before]
  >  LATHE**R** (product of soap use)
  >  BASTED [no change]
- > MUSHES [no change]
  >  LAT**T**ER [seen before]
  >  BAS**H**ED [seen before]
- > **L**USHES [seen before]
  >  **M**ATTER [seen before]
  >  BASHED [no change]
- > LUSHES [no change]
  >  **B**ATTER [seen before]
  >  **M**ASHED (crushed, as potatoes)
- > LUSHES [no change]
  >  BATTE**D** [seen before]
  >  MASHE**R** [seen before]
- > LUSHES [no change]
  >  BAT**H**ED [seen before]
  >  MAS**T**ER [seen before]
- > LUSHES [no change]
  >  BA**S**HED [seen before]
  >  MA**T**TER [seen before]
- > LUSHES [no change]
  >  BASHE**R** [seen before]
  >  MATTE**D** [seen before]
- > LUSHE**R** [seen before]
  >  BASHE**S** [seen before]
  >  MATTED [no change]

Comment: Excellent, excellent work!  Not only did you complete the path, but you matched the shortest possible path (24 steps) as calculated by my word list.  Very impressive.

Comment: And I learned something:  The rest of the world is not nearly so familiar with MUSH/MUSHER/MUSHING as Americans are.  I guess the Alaskan dogsled is part of our "pioneering spirit" or "frontier mythology".  If someone is pulling you in a wagon or sled, is not uncommon to jokingly say, "Mush!  Mush!" and everyone will know what you are referring to.

Comment: @SlowMagic LUSHES was the one I had assumed wasn't a word. MUSHER, even if you don't know about Alaskan culture, could be a tool for mushing food.

Comment: @Randal'Thor — Oh, right, it was Gareth who wasn't familiar with MUSHER.

Answer (score 9):

My answer:

- > MATTED
  >  BASHES
  >  LUSHER
- > MATTED
  >  BUSHES
  >  LASHER
- > BATTED
  >  MUSHES
  >  LASHER
- > BATTED
  >  MUSHER
  >  LASHES
- > BATTER
  >  MUSHED
  >  LASHES
- > BUTTER
  >  MASHED
  >  LASHES
- > BUTTER
  >  LASHED
  >  MASHES
- > BUTTER
  >  LASHES
  >  MASHED
- > BUSTER
  >  LATHES
  >  MASHED
- > LUSTER
  >  BATHES
  >  MASHED
- > LUSTER
  >  BASHES
  >  MATHED
- > LUSHER
  >  BASTES
  >  MATHED
- > LUSHER
  >  BASHES
  >  MATTED

Most questionable word:

> MATHED (an abbreviation for Mathematics Education, or a verbification of "math").

Note that

> American English is being used, both for LUSTER (meaning lustre, not one who lusts) and MATHED.

Comment: There are solution paths which do not involve the word MATHED, since it is an abbreviation.

Comment: BTW, I actually removed LUSTRE from my word list because it seemed to have something to do with a five-year period, which I never even heard of before.  So I figured, "I'm not in Kansas anymore with this word, I better take it out..."

Comment: @SlowMagic I realised after posting this answer that you also allow left-right transpositions. Is it possible with just up-down ones?

Comment: You are permitted to use both up-down and left-right transpositions in any sequence you choose.  For any given problem, however, it is possible that the solution path may consist entirely of up-down transpositions.

Comment: Funny story:  My computer program first divides the entire solution space into disconnected subgraphs.  Then, it chooses the largest subgraphs which contains both up-down and left-right movement, since those are the more interesting and challenging subspaces.  Finally, it computes the longest path within the chosen subgraphs.  However, it is possible that the longest path may happen to avoid all the left-right transpositions in the subspace around it, resulting in a purely up-down path.

Comment: But it would still be challenging for the humans trying to solve it because left-right movements are *possibilities* which must be considered.

Comment: LUSTRE is a perfectly good word even if you don't like the one connected with ancient Roman religious rituals, meaning something like "sheen". I don't much like MATHED, though. (Nor MUSHER or LASHER, for that matter. I mean, it's clear enough what they have to mean, but they don't really feel like real words, if you see what I mean.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan — Sorry, I should have said that I looked for solutions which don't *necessarily* require knowledge of LUSTRE in case the general solving community wasn't familiar with it.  There may be alternate solution paths which do contain it.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan — Wait, what's wrong with MUSHER?  Alaskans and Inuit people would be very familiar with that word!

Comment: I'm neither Alaskan nor Inuit and had never heard that usage of that word.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan — I think I've spotted a novel vacation idea for you...

Comment: I believe that MATHED can be analysed as past of the colloquial verb _to math_ (to do mathematical calculations).

Comment: @Gareth Presumably Peter Mandelson is also neither Alaskan nor Inuit.

Comment: Presumably. Is there some notable association between that august personage and the word MUSHER?

Comment: @Gareth Perhaps he was confused between a musher and ... whatever they use to make guacamole.