# Another series of fortunate (and sideways) transpositions

Tags: wordplay, no-computers, graph-theory, sliding-blocks, word-ladder

Using only a sequence of transpositions, see if you can take this:

[image: start_state]

to this:

[image: finish_state]

while maintaining English words on each of the three horizontals.

At each step, you may transpose any two neighboring letters, either up-down or left-right.

At each step, you must have three horizontal English words.

You might need to know this word: [COAMING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaming).  Other than that, all the words along the way should be quite familiar.

*Maybe you saw the [first version](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93005/a-series-of-fortunate-transpositions) of this puzzle.  Extensive experimental evidence suggests that the fun level of this kind of puzzle increases exponentially with the number of horizontal possibilities, so I have devised this new version which emphasizes sideways movement.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is optimal, but here's my solution

> COATING
> CARTING
> FRAMING
>
> COATING
> CRATING
> FRAMING
>
> CRATING
> COATING
> FRAMING
>
> CRATING
> COATING
> FARMING
>
> CRATING
> COAMING
> FARTING
>
> CRATING
> FOAMING
> CARTING
>
> CARTING
> FOAMING
> CARTING
>
> FARTING
> COAMING
> CARTING
>
> FARMING
> COATING
> CARTING
>
> FARMING
> COATING
> CRATING
>
> FARMING
> CRATING
> COATING
>
> FRAMING
> CRATING
> COATING
>
> FRAMING
> CARTING
> COATING